# Simplegui module for Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, module, python-idle, codeskulptor

Is there any way to install SimpleGUI module in Windows 7 for Python 3.2 with all other module dependencies or does one need to be running Linux do be able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go to:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SimpleGUICS2Pygame/

1. Download whichever Python you use
2. Change the EGG extension to ZIP
3. Extract in Python
4. Instead of 'import simplegui' type: import  SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui

DONE!